# Which Vector Operation is Faster in Unity: new Vector3() vs Vector.up * value vs vector3.Set()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When dealing with the movement and rotation of game objects, I often use different methods for vector operations, such as new Vector3(), Vector.up * value, and movement.Set(). However, I'm not sure about the performance differences between these methods.

Specifically, I want to know which method is faster in the following scenarios:

Using new Vector3() to create a new Vector3 instance;
Using Vector.up * value to create a new Vector3 instance, where value is a scalar;
Using Vector.Set(x, y, z) to set the value of an existing Vector3 instance, where h and v are variables.
I would like to understand the performance differences of these methods in Unity so that I can choose the most efficient method when writing code. Although this performance difference may be negligible, I'm just curious.Thank you for your help!

For example:

```
Vecor3 movement;

1.movement = new(0f,y,0f);

2.movement = Vector.up * y;

3.movement.Set(0, y, 0);
```

Comment: Unity has an excellent profiler. Instead of speed you might also consider garbage creation.

Comment: Very technically speaking `Vector3.up * y` would be the least efficient of the 3, as it performs 3 multiplications (one for each component of the vector). And `new Vector3(0f, y, 0f)` would be the "best" as it creates the object with the correct values right away. Though if that ever would even be noticable is questionable

Comment: See [which is faster](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) from Eric Lippert. In short: don't usk *us* to profile *your* code, instead measure yourself. That way you get way more expressive and meaningful information than any wild guess here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

**It doesn't matter.** Your game is *never* going to be bottlenecked by instantiating these types, unless you are creating far too many of them - which would be a bug in how you've coded things, not a problem with those types. [To once again quote the esteemed Donald Knuth:](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

> "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. **We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.** Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."

Answer (score 0):

In Unity, the performance differences between these methods are generally negligible for most scenarios. You can often choose the one that is more readable or convenient for your code.

Hope this can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Number 1 could be the fastest***

In both situation 1 and 2 you create a new Vector3. Situation 2 could be slower because if we look at the implementation of operator: `Vector3 * float`, we see we instantiate a new Vector and multiply the float by the components of the given vector. Which is more operations.

```
public static Vector3 operator *(Vector3 a, float d)
{
   return new Vector3(a.x * d, a.y * d, a.z * d);
}
```

Situation 3 crashes your code if you dont instantiate a vector beforehand, which makes it negligeable.

**benchmark your code before even thinking about optimizations*

Comment: `Vector3` is a value type so should not incur any 'allocation', and I think you would need to write benchmarks to make conclusions about performance. Just looking at the source may not be super useful since it will go thru so many optimization steps.

Comment: You're right, and I also agree, my assumption probably is invalid depending on the situation. And I agree that testing performance before optimizing code/making assumptions is much more true in practice. Though it may not apply to this situation: it's not a bad habit to check out the source, especially if one is curious.